# Preferred way to include relative reference to JavaScript in VS 2008 nested Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages, relative-path, nested

Our base Masterpage has something like the following

```
  <head runat="server">
   <title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientURL("~/javascript/actions.js")%>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientURL("~/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js")%>"></script>
   <asp:contentplaceholder id="cph_htmlhead" runat="server">

   </asp:contentplaceholder>
  </head>
```

If this Masterpage is the Masterpage for an ASPX page things work fine.

If this Masterpage is the Masterpage for a child Masterpage and then a new ASPX page uses the child Masterpage as it's MasterPage we see:

Server Error in '' Application.

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

**What is the preferred way to include global resources (Javascript/CSS) in a base Masterpage preserving tilde(~) style relative pathing?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the ScriptManager server control:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path = "~/javascript/actions.js" /> 
      <asp:ScriptReference Path = "~/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/javascript/actions.js") %>'></script>
```

Comment: We are currently using the pounded (#) include with a call to databind() on the head element in the base master code behind. But I am looking for something concrete/best practice.

Answer (score 4):

As per [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx),

One tip to take advantage of is the relative path fix-up support provided by the head runat="server" control.  You can use this within Master Pages to easily reference a .CSS stylesheet that is re-used across the entire project (regardless of whether the project is root referenced or a sub-application):

The path fix-up feature of the head control will then take the relative .CSS stylesheet path and correctly output the absolute path to the stylesheet at runtime regardless of whether it is a root referenced web-site or part of a sub-application.